# Jordan content of pre-images of smooth functions

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f$ be a smooth function (i.e. $C^{\infty}(X)$ ) and consider the pre-image $f^{-1}(x>t):=\left\{x\in X: f(x)>t \right\}$. Is this set Jordan measurable?
And how to does one continue to show that these functions are arbitrarily well approximated by simple functions of jordan measurable sets?

Comment: I suppose that even just differentiability is enough..